# HTML5 Video that supports Internet Explorer 6 >?

Tags: html, css, web, html5-video

I would like to use html5 video on our site but wanted to find out if there is any way of adding support for IE6 seeing that some of our clients use old browsers. I am not sure if I inherit the js "modernizr.js" whether this will solve my issue. Please advise or may you please suggest an alternative besides flash?

Comment: Your web page should fall back to flash player in old IE browsers. Please take a look at this article: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/video-for-everybody-html5-video-with-flash-fallback/
If this won't work for you, please google for other JS solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight answer? You simply can't use HTML5 video in old IE.

You'd be best using a jQuery solution. There's a great plugin which handles all this leg-work for you called jPlayer:

http://www.jplayer.org/

Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in the comment above, you should utilize some kind of fallback to Flash and/or Silverlight for browsers non capable of HTML5 video.

For example have a look at [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/), which is working well and has support for IE 6. There's also a chart on their website indicating which technology is used in which browser.